# Does firebase realtime database support batched writes/Transactions?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

If yes I would like to know how can that be done for Android. I aware that one way to do it would be by using Maps and update children, but is this operation atomic?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Realtime Database supports transactions.  A simple search will take you to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).  According to that documentation, it's stated that both batch write and transactions are atomic.

There is also [multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html), which is similar to batch writes.